Where did Albert Camus say the quote “Man is the only creature who refuses to be what he is”?
I am trying to find the origin of this quote so I can reference it in my essay, but can’t seem to find it anywhere online. Does anyone know when or where Camus said this, and if he actually said it? Any help would be appreciated.

There are two versions of the quote.
The oldest version occurs near the end of the introduction to L'Homme révolté / The Rebel and goes as follows:

La révolte, en tout cas, ne pouvait nous fournir ses raisons qu'au terme d'une enquête sur ses attitudes, ses prétentions et ses conquêtes. Dans ses œuvres se trouvent peut-être la règle d'action que l'absurde n'a pu nous donner, une indication au moins sur le droit ou le devoir de tuer, l'espoir enfin d'une création. L'homme est la seule créature qui refuse d'être ce qu'elle est. (…)

Translation:

In any case, revolt could only provide us with its reasons at the end of an investigation into its attitudes, its claims and its conquests. In its works we perhaps find the rule of action that the absurd has not been able to give us, an indication at least of the right or duty to kill, the hope at last of a creation. Man is the only creature that refuses to be what he is.

The second version can be found in the Carnets or notebooks, which were published posthumously. More specifically, it comes from notes written down in 1948 and included in the second volume: Carnets, tome II : Janvier 1942 - mars 1951:

C’est par le refus d’une partie de ce monde que ce monde est vivable ? Contre l’Amor fati. L’homme est le seul animal qui refuse d’être ce qu’il est.

Translation:

It is by the refusal of a part of this world that this world is livable? Against Amor fati. Man is the only animal that refuses to be what he is.

The second version is also quoted in the following articles about Camus:

Michel Eltchaninoff: Albert Camus, carnets d’incarnation, Philosophie magazine, 10.07.2024.
Lucas Favre: Gilbert Merlio : Nietzsche et Camus, ou la dialectique du maître et du disciple, Zone critique, 19.04.2023.


SUch a good answer thank you so much

prétention is claim, not pretentions in that excerpt. And ses oeuvres probably means the rebel's works, his, not its.

@Lambie The antecedent of "ses" is not a person; no rebel or other person is mentioned in the last three sentences preceding the quote.

Yes, right, It goes with raisons. But then, I'd say: revolt could only provide us with reasons at the end of an investigation into the attitudes, claims and conquests it reveals. I don't much like the repetitions of all those its.
